# The picture does not appear after the save

Tags: image-upload

why
after I save, the picture does not appear?

[image]

Comment: We need more info: 1) is the image path correct / what is the path? 2) Are the any console logs (eg in firebug in firefox) 3) Are the permission (file and folder) correct?

Comment: check permission of media folder..

Comment: did you checked the permission?

Comment: I've checked it,,, when I rename the incoming picture. but the time at the front end, appears, when clicked, the picture does not appear.